# Prove that $2^{n+1}>(n+2) \cdot \sin(n)$ for all positive integers n.

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, induction, natural-deduction

**Proof:**
If $P(n)$ represents the given proposition.

(1) Basic Step: $P(n)$ for $n=1$ is
$$2^{1+1}>(1+2) \cdot \sin(1)$$
$$2^{2}>3 \cdot \sin(1)$$
$$4>3 \cdot \sin(1)$$
Since $\sin(n)≤1$ and $1<4/3$ and so $\sin(n)<4/3$ by putting $n=1$, we obtain
$$\sin(1)<4/3 \implies 4>3 \cdot \sin(1)$$
Which is true.

(2) Induction Step: Suppose that $P(n)$ is true for $n=k$, i.e.
Let $$2^{k+1}>(k+2) \cdot \sin(k)$$
To prove that $P(n)$ to be true for $n=k+1$.

$$2^{(k+1)+1}=2^{k+1}2=2\cdot2^{k+1}>2(k+2) \cdot \sin(k)   $$

How to prove $P(n)$ to be true for $n=k+1$. I got stuck here. Would appreciate for your assistance. Also review my proof if there is any mistake while writing.

Comment: You can simply use the fact that $\sin n \leq 1$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then, it is evident that $\left( n + 2 \right) \sin n \leq n + 2 < 2^{n + 1}$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$. The inequality $n + 2 < 2^{n + 1}$ is easier to handle by induction.

Comment: I got it. Thanks. Really helpful trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here classical induction needs some modification.

Step 1. Show that it is true for $n=1$.

Step 2. Since $n+2\ge (n+2)\sin n$, it suffices to show that
$$
2^{n+1}>n+2
$$
for $n\ge 2$, which can be inductively.